# How to compare each element of two different lists?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to compare each element of one list with another list

I actually tried comparing the two list but it comparing only 1st element and giving the answer

```
l = [6, 5, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 6]
```

so the answer I want is the list l2 not l1 because of 6>4, 6>5 how can I get this?

This is what I have done

```
l = [6, 5, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 6]
for i,j in zip(l,l2):
    if(i > j):
        print(l)
    else:
        print(l2)
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: What should happen if the lists are different lengths, or one of them is empty?

Comment: if one is empty the result should be non-empty list. and condition for this problem is it should have same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can sum `+1`, `-1` at every comparison and see who is positive (you didn't tell anything when they are equal):

```
l = [6, 5, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 6]


res = 0
for i,j in zip(l,l2):
    if(i > j):
        res += 1
    else:
        res -= 1

>>> print(l if res > 0 else l2)
[5, 6, 6]
```